# UI Won't build using performSelectoronMainThread

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocoa

I'm using performSelectorInBackground in download and parse some xml. Once the xml is parsed I call performSelectorOnMainThread to build my UI based on values in the xml. The build UI function does get called but nothing gets put onto the screen. It should be o.k to call the main thread from a background thread should it not?

If I don't perform the xml parsing on a background thread the UI add just fine.

```
-(id) myCustomInit:(Data *) data;

{
    if ( self= [super init]) {
            baseURL=data.url;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getXML) withObject:nil];

    }


    return self;

}


-(void) getXML
{
    // Set up a pool for the background task.

    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // XML parsing code removed for brevity



    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleUIOnXMLComplete) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    [pool release];


}

-(void)handleUIOnXMLComplete
{

// add buttons etc to view

    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[self.view addSubview:button];

}
```

**Edit**

This is the code in the parent UIViewController Thats actually adds the view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NewViewData *rld=nil;

    rld=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NewView *controller = [[NewView alloc] myCustomInit:rld ];


    controller.title = rld.Title;
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [table.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    //[table.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: What kind of updates do you do in handleUIOnXMLComplete? You might need to call setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsLayout in that method to redraw the view.

Comment: I pretty much just create a bunch of buttons and sliders and add them to the view. I tried adding setNeedsDisplay & setNeedsLayout at the end of my updateUI function but I have the same problem

Comment: Your two lines in init before 'return self' need to go inside your if block btw.

Comment: handleUIOnXMLComplete deffinately gets called. It's just that the UI won't update

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest either debugging (or lots of NSLogging) inside your handleUIOnXMLComplete method to ensure it is going through the exact code path you think it is.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what happens if you comment out '[pool release];' and then change waitUntilDone:YES to waitUntilDone:NO? (Obviously it will leak memory but this is just a test)

Comment: Also, would like to see the code for handleUIOnXMLComplete if possible!

Comment: @occulus  There was no change in behaviour

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying that. What happens if you just don't do the XML parsing (comment that out) but still have your getXML method run in background and doing performSelectorOnMainThread:? Can UI updates happen then?

Comment: What did you call setNeedsDisplay + setNeedsLayout on, btw? I take it you called it on the containing top-level UIView for your view?

Comment: @occulus, I think you may be onto something. The UIView that wont update is being add to a UINavcontroller. I guess I should be calling setNeedsLayout on that nav controller? How can I do this from the non-showing subview. (commenting out the xml parse code has no effect btw)

Comment: I tried 
 [self.parentViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
 [self.parentViewController.view setNeedsLayout];  but still no joy... WTF :(

Comment: In the UINavigationController for the view In question I call the following as tests from the end of the updateUIFunction. Still no good. 
 [table.navigationController.view setNeedsDisplay];
 [table.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout];
 [table.view setNeedsLayout];
 [table.view setNeedsDisplay];
 
 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
 [self.view setNeedsLayout];

Comment: setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout are red herrings. If you add a subView to a view on the main thread, it should just appear. I'm a bit concerned to see you making a new view and settings self.view though -- do you really need to do that? Try adding things to the existing self.view for now.

Comment: Wouldn't it create a permanent loop if you customInit your PadViewController?

Comment: Does the buttons show if you don't parse the xml?

Comment: @Seyther. About the permanent loop. I don't know about that. The buttons wont show if I call the selector on the main thread

Comment: @dubbeat I realized you didn't set title or image to the button itself in the code above. Would it display if you set something to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggering a call to a method on the main thread, from a background thread, is allowed and fine.

setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay shouldn't need calling -- when you add a subView to a view, the display of the newly added item is triggered anyway.

What happens if you replace your entire handleUIOnXMLComplete method with the following?

```
-(void)handleUIOnXMLComplete
{

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    label.text = @"XXXXXXX YYYYYYYY";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

I did a quick reproduction, as far as I could, of your situation and the above code does work -- I get to see the "XXXXXXX YYYYYYYY" label.

I'd avoid setting a whole new `self.view` by the way -- it's preferable to modify the existing self.view.

By the way, in the code you posted, you're not setting a frame on your custom UIButton! So do something like `button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 160.0);` after you make your button and before you add it to the view.

Comment: well thats weird. I don't see a label

Comment: And the view you're adding stuff to is definitely the currently showing view in the nav controller? And there's no weirdness like some layer on top of the view obscuring anything? addSubview will put your new subview on top of any other subviews, so normally you'll see the thing you've just added on top of the other stuff.

Comment: I edited my question to explain with example how I am trying to add the view.

Comment: If you're still completely perplexed by the behaviour, it might be time for a "make it and break it" approach. Start a new app from one of the samples (e.g. the nav bar sample might be good). Make it do the thing which you're having trouble with and not much else (so do the background threading bit, which adds ui items to a uiview on the main thread). Then start bolting on bits of the real code, bit by bit, to see at which point you break it.

Comment: @occulus I found out what the problem was. If I put the following line in the custom init function and not the update UI function it works. self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]; For some reason it seems that the view needs to be created right off the bat.

Comment: Ah excellent! That was in my answer btw: "I'd avoid setting a whole new self.view by the way -- it's preferable to modify the existing self.view." -- I've seen such a thing create problems before. Feel free to accept my answer then! :)

Comment: Btw, do you need to even add a new view? If it's a UIViewController which is loaded from a nib it probably comes with its own view already.

Comment: the back and forth with you led me in the direction of solving my problem so I'm going to mark this as correct.